# Null check doesn't work as expected in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have these models :

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDetails { get; set; }
    public Bid SelectedBid { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bid> Bids{ get; set; }

}
public class Bid
{
    public int BidID { get; set; }
    public string BidTitle { get; set; }
    public string BidDetails { get; set; }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

And I have this Razor :

```
@if(Model.SelectedBid == null)
{
   <dt>
      Status : 
   </dt>

   <dd>        
      Bid not Selected
   </dd>
}
else
{
   <dt>
      Status : 
   </dt>

   <dd>
      Bid Selected.
   </dd>    
}
```

While debugging in the View, Model has this selected bid :

> base =
>   {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Bid_88FA74D99E4E553A1039D70D55E452C7931E74DCCCA8B5237C0A208B12CCA8C4}
>   But it still accepts null situation.

Here is my controller :

```
 public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
        return View(project);
    }
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with this code? Thanks.

Comment: you should debug the view, and check if `SelectedBid` is null or not

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: @FabioLuz I checked in the View, it's still not null. But it says bid not selected.

Comment: @jason did you mean the `SelectedBid` is not null and the comparison `SelectedBid == null` is returning `true`?

Comment: @FabioLuz yes, I edited the question.

Comment: Are you populating your Model through Linq to SQL

Comment: @AndersAbel I added my Controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your action method:

```
Project project = db.Projects
    .Include(p=>p.SelectedBid)
    .FirstOrDefault(p=>p.ProjectID==Id);
```

Also don't forget to add `System.Data.Entity` namespace.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Can you tell the magic of Include?

Comment: EF doesn't fetch relative objects which associated with requested object from DB. Instead make a proxy object to lazy load the object. Therefore when you check `Model.SelectedBid == null` it returns true because it is not loaded yet and obviously null. But if you debug the code you can see actual data not a null object because debugger loaded the object while you debug the code. By adding include we say to EF fetch included object also and doesn't lazy load it.